# Plugin: Plugin shortcode not show in widget only page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

i have a problem with plugin, shortcode not show in widget (filter enabled)

in normal page work with [wpcouponninja style="vertical"]

Here is the code:

```
function the_content($content){
        if(!preg_match('@\[wpcouponninja\s?(?:style=")?(.*?)(?:"?)\]@',$content,$m))
            return $content;

        if( !is_page() && !is_single() )
            return str_replace($m[0],'',$content);
```

Comment: how to call this "old" plugin in my widget? Please advise,thank you!

Comment: please look at this:
http://postimg.org/image/w376v8b49/#codes